# Use of would for "vagueness"

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

I have been told that modal 'would' can be used to express 'vagueness'. Its usage has been linked below but I'm not fully convinced because I don't know in what kind of context it would be appropriate to use 'would' for 'vagueness'. Does 'would' carry any kind of meanings in those contexts? Is it formal or natural?
 Or 'would' has been used  just for softening the statement?

> 14. [...] You use would , or sometimes would have with a past participle, when you are expressing your opinion about something or seeing if people agree with you, especially when you are uncertain about what you are saying. *[vagueness] ⇒ I think you'd agree he's a very respected columnist. ⇒ I would have thought it a proper job for the Army to fight rebellion. ⇒ 'Was it much different for you when you started at the Foreign Office?'—'Worse, I'd expect.'. ⇒ I would imagine she's quite lonely living on her own.*

Source: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would

Comment: *Vague* seems a very, well, *vague* term for these uses. *Tentative* might be better, advancing an opinion you're unwilling to maintain too strongly, either because you are uncertain or because you don't want to appear too assertive.

Comment: Could you please try to eliminate my confusion of 'would' for vagueness, contexual examples is needed to understand it. what kind of meaning 'would' carries when it's used in those contexts?

Comment: Not sure why they wrote "vagueness". I would go with "uncertainty" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that *vagueness* is at all a satisfactory way to describe the usage of [would](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) in any of the examples that the excerpt quoted.

Here is a much better definition of would meaning **OPINION - used to express an opinion in a polite way without being forceful**. Here are the examples that my link quotes:

> I would think we need to speak to the headteacher about this first.

Here you are politely suggesting that we need to speak to the head teacher.

> It's not what we would have expected from a professional service

Here you are politely saying that you expected better work from a professional- for example, an architect, accountant, builder or decorator.

If you find **would** used before words like **say**, **think**, **expect**, then one possible interpretation is that it is a polite expression of opinion- however many have other interpretations. If you are not sure, check out the **would** link above for other meanings. Here are some examples that definitely are polite opinions:

> Even amidst the unpleasant reality of my divorce, I **would expect** somebody in the church to understand that there can surely be a note of justice and peaceful resolution in this process. [Devotions for the Divorcing](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=cimmN4Ro78EC&pg=PA26&dq=%22I%20would%20expect%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22I%20would%20expect%22&f=false)
>
> I **would think** an emigration level at least as large as the 1985-1990 figure (130,000) would be more appropriate. [Revised estimates and projections of international migration](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=Pua59HhS3qUC&pg=PA64&dq=%22I%20would%20think%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm8Ke-vrXNAhVGrJQKHYPkAbwQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22I%20would%20think%22&f=false)
>
> I **would expect** from him enough work that I wouldn't feel guilty about asking him.  [Don't expect applause](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=jb0GAAAAMAAJ&q=%22I%20would%20expect%22&dq=%22I%20would%20expect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiwIe-vbXNAhVDJpQKHXeABmM4ChDoAQghMAI)
>
> I **would say** this, that the one thing you cannot do is to act not-acting.  [Holding and Interpretation](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=88NCMqGtKHwC&pg=PA131&dq=%22I%20would%20say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOhIbyvbXNAhVHHpQKHdnICyIQ6AEIPTAG#v=onepage&q=%22I%20would%20say%22&f=false)

Note that we can make a polite opinion more formal by replacing **I** with  **one**:

> **One would expect** people to remember the past and imagine the future.  [Livelihood and Resistance](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=tqJ3kpOhUAwC&pg=PA218&dq=%22one%20would%20expect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ5Izxv7XNAhVCEpQKHeKyCbYQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22one%20would%20expect%22&f=false)

The example that you asked about:

> I would have thought it a proper job for the Army to fight in the rebellion.

The speaker is politely expressing an opinion "It is the proper job of the army to fight in the rebellion". The view is expressed in the past "would have thought", which suggests that actual events differ from what the speaker expected. I don't know the context, but it seems likely that the army has not taken any action to deal with the rebellion.

Comment: What is the meaning of sentence "It's not what we would have expected from a professional service"

is it in past tense?

Comment: It's what you would say if you ask a professional (architect, accountant, maybe even a decorator or builder)  to do some work and they do not do a good job. Afterwards, you say "It's not what I would have expected...", describing what your opinion would have been before you saw the work they actually did.

Comment: You may be correct to say, i tend to understand simple english language. so, i haven't understood yet what you mean to say. It would be better if you could involve the meanings of such sentences clearly in your answer itself with simple language

Comment: I would like to draw the attention of other experts to this Topic: "Use of would for vagueness". I'm expecting the helpfull responses

Comment: Java Lette@ Do you mean to say that the sentence ''It's not what  I would have expected from you" is conditional ? Because it looks likes that. If It's not, does it also imply the desire of the speaker ?

Comment: Java lette@ what I desire mean is: "I would have done the job but I didn't have enough time."
here the speaker had desire to do the job but he didn't have enough time. Thus, the "unfulfiled desire".

Comment: Java Lette@your answer would be more helpfull if you could provide more example sentences with their meanings.

Comment: Java Lette@ could you please respond me?

Comment: @yubrajsharma, you need to put the @ in front of the name, not after it. ''It's not what I would have expected from you" is not conditional. It is expressing a polite comment about some action that occurred in the past. "I would have done the job but I didn't have enough time." **would have** suggests willingness in the past. The **but** indicates that I was unable to do what I wanted.

Comment: @javaLette Now i'm puzzled between thesd two:
Can I say
 "I would have thought Tom the best expert in this stackoverflow.com."
or,
I would think Tom the best expert in this stackoverflow.com"
so, what's the difference in meaning between these two sentence ?

Comment: **would think** is an expression of current opinion . **would have thought** expresses past opinion- presumably it's past opinion because Tom disappointed you in some way.

Comment: I'm going to ask a similar question in ELL which will be full of details or specific opinions

Comment: @JavaLette, could you please include the example" I would have thought it a proper job for the Army to fight in the rebellion." In your answer with its meanings ? I'm in grace period of bounty ,Please do it for me

Comment: @javaLette, If I accept your answer, is it what it's called offering you the bounty ?

Comment: It seems that I did get the bount. Thanks, Yubraj.

Answer (score 2):

Using "would" to create vagueness is an option. "Would" creates a sense, in some cases, of potential or "the about to happen." Take a look at the example sentence below:

> Would you like to go to the party?

In this question, "would" creates the potential options of "yes" or "no." We don't know the response yet, and because there are multiple responses, the result is impossible to determine, and thus, in loose terms, vague. You ave an example of a statement, not a question, so let's take a look at another example:

> I would have thought it a proper job for the Army to fight in the rebellion.

In this sentence, "I would have thought..." implies that the speaker did think that it was a proper job at some point under some circumstances, but now has a different opinion. Once again, because we don't know what that opinion is, a vagueness becomes apparent.

---

The use of the word "would" can create some form of vagueness, but I do not feel that that is a good way of describing what the word does. "Would" makes a statement more indirect, which can open more doors of interpretation and thus create room for a form of vagueness. I like the idea of potential better that vagueness, but vagueness is still somewhat applicable.

Comment: Sam k@ And what about the example sentences that is in my question, it would be better if you could address them.

Comment: @yubrajsharma Well, out of the sentences you provided, only two of them use the word "would." I addressed the first one in my answer, and that explanation is much the same for the second one. "I would imagine" adds a hint of potential to the the normal verb "I imagine," which is more definite.

Comment: Sam k's@ I would like to ask you the same question that I've asked to@ java Lette . Please respond me.

Comment: I've asked  JavaLette@ different  questions but he hasn't replied me yet. I'm also asking the same question to you.

Comment: The reason he may not have replied is because the "@" has to go at the beginning of the name (@yubrajsharma). But anyways, the sentence you asked about in your comment is saying that whatever the professional service did, it was not what the speaker was expecting. It is in the perfect tense, so yes it is in the past tense. For your other questions, they don't make much sense, so I can't answer them.

Comment: Sam k@ ok, i don't know why you said that didn't make much sense to you, but What i mean to ask that is to understand the contradictional use of would. Because in that sentence 'would' might have been used as conditional.

Comment: If the sentence in past why The speaker said "It is not" instead of saying "It wasn't"

Comment: @yubrajsharma As you mentioned, you are an English learner so there's that. But anyways, the sentence is both present and perfect. There is some complicated grammar here, so I won't go into detail, but the "It is not" part makes the sentence applicable to what is going on currently, while the "would have expected" part makes what the sentence is about past tense.

Comment: I got it what you mean , but  Now,I'm puzzled in your second example in your answer: "I would have thought it a proper job for the Army to fight in the rebellion." How this sentence is different from "I had thought it a proper job for the Army to fight in the rebellion" ? I think their differences makes me clear to the use of would in formar sentence.

Comment: @yubrajsharma By saying "I would have thought" means that if the current conditions were different, you would think whatever follows in the sentence. "I had thought" means that, in the past, you thought whatever follows. The "would have" is in the perfect tense, while the "had" is in the pluperfect tense, which is slightly different. This is where the grammar gets a bit more detail-oriented/complicated.

Comment: sam k@ After reading your comment,  I would say the sentence "I would have thought" is past tense of "I would think or I would say" which means showing openion in a polite way.Would you agree with me about it ? ," I think I have to ask another question for better explanation  about this Topic.what would you suggest me ?

Comment: I thinh that "would" is extremely common in native speakers's speech. For example, they usually answer questions on the stackoverflow.com using "would" even when they are 100% sure and have every explanation and authentic source to support their answers.

Comment: You are correct. "I would have thought" is a past tense version of "I would think." "Would" is called a conditional, so it alters the main verb, which can be in any tense. It is often used to be less forceful with an opinion or statement, and thus be more polite. As a native speaker of English, I can attest to how common the use of "would" is. We use it very often, even if we know we are correct. I would (see what I did there) not create a new question. You already placed a bounty on this one, and both respondents put a lot of time into their answers. I would just approve an answer and move on

Comment: I would agree with your openion. I would have thought English as a Easy Language but it's not infact. I would think there are many uses of would which many Non-natives find difficult to understand. ( I've used 'would' here, please tell me is it correct in my comment ?

Comment: @yubrajsharma The first sentence really doesn't need it. The second one is correct. The third one is technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

My two pence. The term *vagueness* is indeed vague as someone else already mentioned but this is something Collins Dictionary people have chosen and, for justice's sake, they explained what they meant by this term in this very quote:

> [...] You use would , or sometimes would have with a past participle,
>   when you are expressing **your opinion about something or seeing if
>   people agree with you**, especially when you are **uncertain about what
>   you are saying**. [vagueness]